# Program is not functioning

Tags: python

I created a game where you (player1) has to guess a higher number then player2 (the computer). You have 3 guesses. My problem is when you "win', the program loops the message and does not ask "do you want to play again". Also when you have 0 guesses left, the answer "guess a number" keeps

Comment: Only a moderator can delete your question now that it has answers. You can ask a mod by clicking the "flag" button below the question.

Comment: I haven't posted an answer. You should flag a mod like I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

While loops in python aren't immediately obvious.

What do you think the output of the following is?

```
counter = 0
while counter < 5:
  while counter < 10:
      counter = counter + 1
      print(counter)
```

It is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

This is because the program doesn't leave the inner while loop until the counter < 10 condition is no longer true.

The reason "You win!" keeps getting printed is because num1 is still contained within Numbers. If you want to change num1, you should do it within the while numGuesses != 0 loop

Also, when you no longer have any guesses left and want to replay the game, the code has no way of reentering the while numGuesses != 0 loop. You should therefore put the if numGuesses == 0 condition within the while loop

```
import random
player2num = random.randrange(1,16)
numGuesses = 3 
print("Welcome to 'Guess Smart'!. Your goal as Player 1 is to guess a higher number then Player 2. You have 3 guesses. Only choose numbers from the list. Good Luck!")
Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print(Numbers)
while numGuesses != 0:
  num1 = int(input("guess a number: "))
  while not num1 in Numbers:
    print("please choose a number in the list")
    num1 = int(input("guess a number: ")) 
  if num1 in Numbers: 
    if num1 > player2num:
      print("You win!")
      numGuesses = 0
    elif num1 < player2num: 
      print("your number is too low, guess again")
      numGuesses = numGuesses - 1
      print("you have this many guesses left: ",numGuesses)
  if numGuesses == 0:
    playAgain = input("do you want to play again? (answer yes or no): ")
    if playAgain == "yes":
      numGuesses = 3
    elif playAgain == "no":
      print("end of game")
      break
```

Comment: can the answers be deleted, in order for me to delete my question?

Comment: I forgot I'm turning this in for a project and I can't use websites for help. I am not going to use the answers for help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in this code.
1. The inner while loop is infinite. Change it to if statement.
2. It asks player1 for 4 times to guess. Compare the code below for the fix.
3. There is an indentation error at the last line.
4. Be mindful strings are case sensitive. It asks for "yes"/"no" but checks for "yes/"No".
5. When the player1 finishes the game and wants to play again, it only asks for one other guess (rather than restarting the game). If you would like to restart the game, you can use another while loop (while playAgain: ...) and set the default values as yes.

```
import random
player2num = random.randrange(1,16)
numGuesses = 3 
print("Welcome to 'Guess Smart'!. Your goal as Player 1 is to guess a higher number then Player 2. You have 3 guesses. Only choose numbers from the list. Good Luck!")
Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print(Numbers)
playAgain = "yes"
while playAgain == "yes":
  while numGuesses != 0:
    num1 = int(input("guess a number: "))
    while not num1 in Numbers:
      print("please choose a number in the list")
      num1 = int(input("guess a number: ")) 
    if num1 in Numbers: 
      if num1 > player2num:
        print("You win!")
        numGuesses = 0
      elif num1 < player2num: 
        print("your number is too low, guess again")
        numGuesses = numGuesses - 1
        print("you have this many guesses left: ",numGuesses)
  if numGuesses == 0:
    playAgain = "no"
    playQuestion = input("do you want to play again? (answer yes or no): ")
    if playQuestion == "yes":
      playAgain = "yes"
      numGuesses = 3
    elif playQuestion == "no":
      print("end of game")
```

Comment: can the answer be deleted, in order for me to delete my question?

Comment: I forgot I'm turning this in for a project and I can't use websites for help. I am not going to use the answers for help